# Finding rows lacking certain children

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a translation database and I need to find variables which aren't translated into certain core languages, and also variables which are translated into one certain language but not another.

A simplified version of the database looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE var (
       id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
       name varchar(15)
);

CREATE TABLE language (
       id smallint unsigned primary key auto_increment,
       name varchar(31),
       ietf varchar(5)
);

CREATE TABLE translation (
       var_id  int unsigned not null,
       lang_id smallint unsigned not null,
       val varchar(128),
       PRIMARY KEY(var_id, lang_id),
       CONSTRAINT trans_fk_var
                  FOREIGN KEY(var_id)
                  REFERENCES var(id),
       CONSTRAINT trans_fk_lang
                  FOREIGN KEY(lang_id)
                  REFERENCES language(id)
);


insert into var (name) values ('var1'),('var2'),('var3');
insert into language (name, ietf) values ('German', 'de'), ('Spanish', 'es'), ('German (Austria)', 'de-AT'), ('Spanish (Mexico)', 'es-MX');
insert into translation values (1,1, 'string 1'), (1,2, 'string 2'), (1,3, 'string 3'), (2,1, 'string 4'), (2,2, 'string 5'), (3,1, 'string 6');
```

The queries I'm trying to figure out are:

- Which variables are not translated to at least one of the languages 1
  and 2 (in this example var 3)
- Which variables are translated to language 2 but not language 4 (in this example variable 1 and 2)

Said queries will be executed fairly often, and the database is large, so I need the queries to be as cheap as possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  So your first question can be phrased as:

```
select var_id
from translations t
group by var_id
having count(*) < (select count(*) from language);
```

And the second as:

```
select var_id
from translations t
group by var_id
having sum(lang_id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(lang_id = 4) = 0;
```